# php - loop through dates to predict 4on 40ff shift schedule

Tags: php, loops, date

Gooooood evening all...

Edit:

I'm trying to write a php script to output the dates I will work for the remainder of the year if given a specific start date.

For example I start on 2020-05-14 and work for 4 days then take 4 days off.
This continues for the remainder of the year.

I would like to output the dates i will work and think it could probably be done using the php for loop, however i've been thinking of how to do this for too long and can't seem to break through the wall.

The start of my code is this:

```
<?php

$z = date("z",mktime(0,0,0,05,14,2020));

for($i=$z;$i<=365;$i+=4) {

    echo("$i<br>");

}

?>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated on a possible solution.

Comment: So you work four days then have four days off, starting from when?

Comment: This isn't that clear.  On SO you usually present your failed attempt, adding expected inputs and outputs.  Try and edit your question to reflect that, otherwise I fear it will only receive negative feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You're computing the day of the year (e.g. for 2020-05-14, that would be 134), which is fine for letting your script know when to stop.

However, you're wanting to output dates, where you're currently outputting the day of the year instead.

I think there's an easier way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

```php
<?php    

$start = new \DateTime("2020-05-14 00:00:00");    
$end = new \DateTime($start->format("Y") . "-12-31 00:00:00");    
$four = new \DateInterval("P4D");    
$one = new \DateInterval("P1D");    
$format = 'Y-m-d';    

$date = $start;    
while ($date <= $end) {    
    echo $date->format($format), PHP_EOL;    
    for ($day = 2; $day <= 4; $day++) {    
        $date->add($one);    
        echo $date->format($format), PHP_EOL;    
    }    
    $date->add($four);    
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thats perfect thank you. I have basic knowledge of PHP which gets me by but something like this is beyond me TBH. Works perfectly thank you, and it also gives me an insight into the DateTimne() class to and how it can be used. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Toe-neeeeee Glad it worked. You're welcome. An upvote to my answer would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: I've up-voted it but as i've a reputation below 15 it doesnt show.